# Left and right image responsive in css and html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

I am building a landing page with fixed left and right image and content in the middle. in desktop view its working fine but in mobile view the images overlapping the contents. how do I fix this?

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm col-lg mt-5 mb-5">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <img src="images/me.svg" class="img-fluid" style="width: 200px">
                </div>
                <div class="text-center" style="  font-family: 'CustomFont',SceneStd-Light;    color: #969595;">
                        UAE’s largest online plant store launching soon in 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row pb-5">
            <div class="col-sm text-center">
                <img src="images/bahrain.svg"  style="height: 150px">
                <div class="text-center pb-2 pt-2"><span>Bahrain</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center">
                <img src="images/saudi.svg"  style="height: 150px">
                <div class="text-center pb-2 pt-2"><span>Bahrain</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm text-center">
                <img src="images/kuwait.svg"  style="height: 150px">
                <div class="text-center pb-2 pt-2"><span>Bahrain</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm col-lg mt-5 mb-5">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/ae.svg" class="img-fluid" style="width: 200px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/uae.svg" style="height: 150px"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center pb-2 pt-2"><span>Visit our UAE store</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    <a href="#">    <img src="images/right.png" class="img-responsive layout-image"  ></a>

    </div>
```

```
.left{ 

  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;}

.right{
     top: 0px; 
  right: 0;
  /*width: 150px;*/
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;}
  .layout-image{height: 100%}
```

In Desktop view
[image]

In mobile view
[image]

How do I fix this in mobile and tablet view.

Comment: do you use bootstrap? if yes what version?

Comment: Use `@media selectors` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries I'd add `left:100px` to `.left` and `right:100px` to `.right`

Comment: @Roy if the OP use bootstrap better to use bootstrap classes...

Comment: add z-index make it  on those images.

Comment: @anusha you have to decrease the images width, height sizes and apply z-index. If you can provide snippet it will help to solve the problem

Comment: what z-index I should give?

Comment: how to solve this using bootstrap??

Comment: what version of bootstrap?

Comment: bootstrap latest version 4

Comment: @anusha z-index to the circles which come upon the tree images

Comment: Use z-index for content div..and it should be more than leaf div

Answer (score 1):

```css
.dashed-box { 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: dashed;
  height: 8em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.gold-box { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3; /* put .gold-box above .green-box and .dashed-box */
  background: gold;
  width: 80%;
  left: 60px;
  top: 3em;
}
.green-box { 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2; /* put .green-box above .dashed-box */
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 20%;
  left: 65%;
  top: -25px;
  height: 7em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index -->

<div class="dashed-box">Dashed box
  <span class="gold-box">Gold box</span>
  <span class="green-box">Green box</span>
</div>
```

There are multiple ways to do this, are mentioned my @bpolar you can use the z-index. Another way of doing it is with media selectors which would allow you to have different css properties for different screen sizes

Example:

```
@media (min-width:1281) {
    image {
        width:200px;
    }
}
@media (max-width:1280) {
    image {
        width:100px;
    }
}
```

This code will display images in different sizes for different display-widths, you could see them as if-statements.
The benefit of this approach is that you have finer control over how it appears on different display configurations. That being said I think the best option is a combination of the two.

If you need more info about the z-index that can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Z-index on those images. The trick is that the content needs higher position than the images.

Example:

.img_class {z-index: -1}

Comment: somebody please help me out

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the `!important` keyword after the z-index for `.left` and `.right` classes and then explicitly set a higher z-index on `.container` class it appears to work ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>plantshop.me</title>
        <link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <style>
            .left{ 
                z-index: -1!important;
                left: 0;
                width: 150px;
                height: 100%;
                position: fixed;
            }

            .right{
                z-index: -1!important;
                top: 0px; 
                right: 0;
                /*width: 150px;*/
                height: 100%;
                position: fixed;
            }

            .layout-image{
                height: 100%
            }

            .container{
                z-index:2!important;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="left"><img src="images/left.png" class="img-responsive layout-image" ></div>

        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-sm col-lg mt-5 mb-5'>
                    <div class='text-center'>
                        <img src='images/me.svg' class='img-fluid' style='width: 200px'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='text-center' style='font-family:'CustomFont',SceneStd-Light; color: #969595;'>
                        UAE’s largest online plant store launching soon in 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row pb-5'>
                <div class='col-sm text-center'>
                    <img src='images/bahrain.svg'  style='height: 150px'>
                    <div class='text-center pb-2 pt-2'><span>Bahrain</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm text-center'>
                    <img src='images/saudi.svg'  style='height: 150px'>
                    <div class='text-center pb-2 pt-2'><span>Bahrain</span></div>
                </div>
                <div class='col-sm text-center'>
                    <img src='images/kuwait.svg'  style='height: 150px'>
                    <div class='text-center pb-2 pt-2'><span>Bahrain</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-sm col-lg mt-5 mb-5'>
                    <div class='text-center'>
                        <a href='#'><img src='images/ae.svg' class='img-fluid' style='width: 200px'></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class='text-center'>
                        <a href='#'><img src='images/uae.svg' style='height: 150px'></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class='text-center pb-2 pt-2'><span>Visit our UAE store</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class='right'><a href="https://plantshop.ae/"> <img src="images/right.png" class="img-responsive layout-image" /></a></div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to increase the z-index like z-index:9999 of behrain image and leaf z-index to 9 in mobile view.